# Find the top 2 values in each row

Tags: r, dplyr

Right now I have a dataframe in this form:

```
year  blue  red   yellow  orange  pink  white
2012   1     2      3        4       5    6
2013   12    14     28       11      0    5
```

If I want to find the top 2 of each row and have this dataframe as a result:

```
year  color   n
2012  white   6
2012  pink    5
2013  yellow  28
2013  red     14
```

How do I do that in base R or `dplyr`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(color, value, -year) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  distinct(value) %>% 
  arrange(desc(value)) %>% 
  # now we select the TOP 2
  slice(1:2) %>% 
  # now we add the colors
  left_join(df %>% 
              gather(color, value, -year)) %>% 
  select(1, 3, 2)
```

output is:

```
 # A tibble: 4 x 3
 # Groups:   year [2]
    year color  value
   <int> <chr>  <int>
 1  2012 white      6
 2  2012 pink       5
 3  2013 yellow    28
 4  2013 red       14
```

If you further work with this dataframe, don't forget to `ungroup()` it.

Answer (score 0):

We can `gather` and then use `top_n` to get top 2 values.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(color, n, -year) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  top_n(2, n)


#   year color      n
#  <int> <chr>  <int>
#1  2013 red       14
#2  2013 yellow    28
#3  2012 pink       5
#4  2012 white      6
```

---

Or we could also `arrange` and `slice`

```
df %>%
  gather(color, n, -year) %>%
  arrange(year, desc(n)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  slice(c(1, 2))
```

Comment: First example does not yield result. Missing `arrange(year, desc(n ))`. Also, IMHO it's bad practice to name columns as functions... like `n` which could be confused with `n()`

Comment: @Nettle Both the answers work for me. I am using this data, `df <- structure(list(year = 2012:2013, blue = c(1L, 12L), red = c(2L, 
14L), yellow = c(3L, 28L), orange = c(4L, 11L), pink = c(5L, 
0L), white = c(6L, 5L)), .Names = c("year", "blue", "red", "yellow", 
"orange", "pink", "white"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))`. And yes, I agree I could have named it something better than `n` for sure. :)

Comment: your first solution begins with 14 and ends with 6. The desired result begins with 6 and ends with 14. (PS. I'm a fan!)

Comment: `1+2+3` is same as `3+2+1`. I am not clear if the order is important in reference to this question (if it is then sure we can add `arrange(year, desc(n))`).  As far as I could understand, OP wants top 2 values for each row which the answer returns.